# Python Openpyxl display left to right

Tags: python, openpyxl

I was wondering how to adjust display left to right / right to left with openpyxl or if its even possible.
haven't really found anything in the documantation, maybe im blind.
thanks in advance :)

Comment: This question is too vague.

Answer (score 9):

Try This

```
worksheet.sheet_view.rightToLeft = True
```

I've found it after digging in the code of worksheet.py and views.py

Answer (score -1):

As A-Palgy said you have to add

`worksheet.sheet_view.rigtToleft = True`

but first, you have to enable that feature in the views.py file in this path:

`C:\python36\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\views.py`

and edit the line :

`rightToLeft = Bool(allow_none=True)`

to

`rightToLeft = Bool(allow_none=False)`